# Use 'clean document' from Inkscape via command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, inkscape

I'm looking for a method to call the 'clean up document' action of InkScape via its command line.

I have over 600 svg files which are very big. If I open them in InkScape, call 'clean up document' and then 'save' they are significantly smaller.

Is it possible to do this from command line so I could write a bat file to do all the work?

TIA Michael

Answer (score 2):

I found it. It is possible!

Here is my batch file:

```
for /r %%i in (*.svg) do (
    "c:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.com" --verb FileVacuum --verb FileSave --verb FileClose --verb FileQuit "%%i"
)
```

This works for InkScape 0.92.4.
They say that --verb is deprecated, but I found that --actions so far doesn't work.

Comment: Or `--vacuum-defs`, which has the same effect.